# In AngularJS tutorial select only one instance, or the first instance in an array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to select only the first instance of an array in angular instead of using ng-repeat. I was thinking something like ng-instance, or ng-specificinstance but they don't exist.  Also how should I define my javascript variable and what is the standard for referencing it in my html: "phoneinfos" or "phoneinfo" if its only one entity.  Also should all things with lots of items should it always end in an s?

**Current HTML:**

```
<div id="searchtab-1" style="height:1.5em;" ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
   <label ng-repeat="phoneinfo in phoneinfos">{{phoneinfo.count}}</label>
</div>
```

**HTML Attempt:**

```
<div id="searchtab-1" style="height:1.5em;" ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
   <label ng-instance="phoneinfo">{{phoneinfo.count}}</label>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
Defined variable:
 $scope.phoneinfo = [{ 'count': '555' }, {'type': 'mobile'}];
```

Comment: When you say first instance, of your phoneInfo? meaning "count" property of the first object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
<div id="searchtab-1" style="height:1.5em;" ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
     <label>{{phoneinfo.count}}</label>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.phoneinfo = {
    count: '555',
    type: 'mobile'
};
```

If you actually need the data to stay exactly as is, you could do this as well (but it doesn't look very pretty to me):

```
<div id="searchtab-1" style="height:1.5em;" ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
    <label>{{phoneinfos[0].count}}</label>
</div>
```

As for the names ending in s, I find it a good practice for the exact reason that you can write `item in items`, and it also signals that it's an array, but that is a matter of personal taste.

Comment: Thx.  Why did I have to remove the angle brackets? []

Comment: I recommend reading up on on some Javascript tutorials to understand what was the difference.

Basically, you created an array (a list), with two objects (key->value pairs). First item in list had the key 'count', the other had the key 'type'. Unless you are actually dealing with multiple items, using a list is not recommended.